FX Console crashing AE 2024 when I take a snapshot then open its gallery
What it says... FX Console v1.0.5 is causing a crash every time I take a snap shot then try to view it in the gallery.
Even on a new project with one empty comp.

Which is a shame because I use it all the time. Any workarounds?
MacBookPro M1 Max running Sonoma 14.6.1 with AE v24.6.1

I was running into the same problem as you. I just found a solution that worked for me. I opened FX Console settings, reset settings in there, cleared the cache and then selected a save location folder. Now everything works again. For how long I do not know.
